# can we use IOS Enterprise account for Testing, then use IOS Developer account once final and upload to app store?

Tags: ios, iphone, enterprise

I have this question.

If we have two iOS accounts:

1. Developer Account
2. Enterprise Account

Can we use iOS Enterprise account for Testing, then use iOS Developer account once final and upload to app store?

Is this possible? is this legal?

Thanks! :)

Comment: That depends on why you are doing it.  Why aren't you using the normal company account for testing?

Comment: @Jim - Enterprise will be more convenient for testing. We are a global company, so the testers are from different countries and we don't need to add their UDIDs for enterprise. so we want to use the Enterprise account for testing only. then once everything is final, we will use our Distribution account to upload it to app store.

Comment: Why does them being in different countries matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Yes, it is legal as far as I understand it (as long as you aren't just throwing it out in the open, you should limit it to parties that are affiliated with or contracted by your business).  You should ensure that all the enterprise copies get deleted upon release though.

Comment: @borrrrden - i believe you are correct. I have also contacted apple to verify on this. Thanks :)

Comment: @carlo My company is also doing it the exact way that you described

Answer (score 1):

It's not a matter of being legal or not, it is what makes sense. With a developer account you can distribute your app to devices and let people test it, [although there are better ways of doing it.](https://testflightapp.com/)

Comment: yes i know, but my manager wants to use the enterprise account for convenience in testing only. In the enterprise way we dont need to add their UDIDs anymore. this is less hassle and saves all of our time. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it with your enterprise account. enterprise acc. does not requires your testing team member device UDID, so it is more beneficial for your product.

When it will approved by your testers, you can upload it on app store with your distribution account.

Comment: I believe this is correct. whew i will verify this with apple too. thanks :)